# Remove all if None English from a string

Tags: php

I have a string that contain None-English :

```
អត���រាប���រូរប���រាក���ថ���ង���ទី 03-06-2011 ម������ង 07:30 នាទី រូបិយប���ឞ���ឞ​ អត���រា​ ទិញចូល លក���ច���ញ រូបិយប���ឞ���ឞ​ប���រទ�����​អា�����ីប���រាក���រ���ល (1usd)4,1004,107បាត ថ���ឡង��� (1usd)30.1530.23រុង
```

Anybody could tell me how can I remove the non-english string

Comment: Well if even a Unicode-based operating system cannot show those characters, I don't know what's happening.

Comment: Are you trying to keep letters and numbers and certain punctuation marks? Your example isn't exactly "English".

Comment: @DOK I think he intends to drop it down into just the basic latin alphanumerics, plus basic symbols...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HM....

maybe you can write your allowed chars and use preg_replace like this:

```
preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9#\(\),\. ]/i','',$string);
```

Comment: looks like we're close to one another - I don't think you whitelisted hyphens though.  we both missed colons however; I just edited my answer to add that in.

Comment: @obs: that was only to give him an example. I am pretty sure you got that but you want to sponsor your answer xD

Answer (score 3):

does this work?

```
preg_replace('/[^\#0-9a-zA-Z\.\,\-\(\): ]+/', '', $string);
```

Comment: @yes123 if we keep bumping into each other like this today, it'll have to end in a lightsaber duel. D: -- @newbie, awesome, good to know

Comment: lightsaber AHAHAHAH. anyway on SO it's called Fastest Gun in the West duel. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem  +1 for lightsaber anyway regardless of your answer

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove anything that's not in the ASCII printable range, nor tab, linefeed or carriage return:

```
preg_replace('/[^\t\n\r\x20-\x7E]+/', '', $string);
```